# Running application object in Scala from SBT project's root directory in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm trying to run very basic Hello World inside IntelliJ IDEA and something goes wrong.

```
mkdir HelloWorld
cd HelloWorld

cat > Hello.scala
object Hello {
  def main(args : Array[String]) {
    println("Hello World")
  }
}

cat > build.sbt
scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("Hello")
```

And everything goes smooth, as I've expected from sbt which I use pretty often

```
sbt run
...
[info] Running Hello 
Hello World
```

After that I'm trying to bring this project to the IDEA with which I have no experience.

ItelliJ IDEA 13.0 have support for both scala and sbt from core plugins. So it can open `HelloWorld` folder as idea project with auto-converting.

I'm forced to create new run configuration after pressing *Menu -> Run -> Run*. I select `New Application` here.

The Form emerges and I'm required to fill it. The problem lies inside "Main class" option. I select *"Project" -> "HelloWorld[helloworld]" -> "Hello"* and receive **"Hello is not accepotable" error message**. This messages appears regardles of what is value is set to the "Use classpath of mod..." option.

I've tried both auto-import from the IDEA core plugin and "gen-idea" from the sbt-idea plugin. They all initialize no usable run configuration and I can not fill with something usable myself.

How can I configure usable correct run configuration for the project?

Comment: I don't programming on Scala but this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gzjoIOifb6I) may be helpful for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following version of IntelliJ IDEA **13.0.2**...

[image]

...the only way to be able to execute `Hello` application was to **move** it to **src/main/scala** directory. The menu item **Run 'Hello'** worked fine then. No need to define a configuration - just right-click the object class and select the menu item. It will then create an appropriate configuration.